# What is the meaning of "comprising the system"

Tags: meaning

In a thermodynamics book, I came across the following sentence:

> An extrinsic property is a property that is independent of the nature
>   of the media comprising the system.

However, what does that mean by "the media comprising the system". Is it the media that the system lives, or the type of the media that the system has ?

**Edit:**

*Media* means medium in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extrinsic property is a property that is independent of the nature of the media comprising the system.

means: the nature of the media that makes up the system.

or: the nature of the media that the system is comprised of, or made up of.

The process consists of two steps. [Merriam Webster for consist]
The process is made up of two steps. [Merriam Webster made up of]

**In English, learners can be confused about the active and passive here:**

the media comprises the system.
the system is comprised of the media.

They mean the same thing.

So in this:
An extrinsic property is a property that is independent of the nature of the media comprising the system.

The nature of the medium is properties A, B and C: they make up the system. Anything (any property) outside of that is an extrinsic property.

Comment: So, it the medium of the parts of the system, that the property is independent of ?

Comment: Right; it's saying that no matter what media are used to make up this system, it will always have the extrinsic property.

Comment: Forget medium of the parts.